# Where should "Issue with MS Exchange Client Mac 2011" question be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> I have installed the native Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2011 client on
>   my MBP and it's been running fine for 6 months.
>
> Two weeks ago, I moved all emails to a subfolder I created with the
>   name "archive."
>
> Since then, Microsoft Outlook is stuck in a perpetual synch state. 
>   (Synching with Exchange Server)
>
> I want to undo this but cannot.
>
> I tried removing the app and the data directories, but upon
>   reinstalling the old data was still intact.
>
> If there is no way to cancel, I would like to at least (a) wipe it
>   clean (for real), and (b) put up with the large first time download of
>   messages.
>
> Any guidance would be appreciated.

Which Stack Exchange site is the best to pose this question?  Seems like there ought to be a "Mac" subdomain.

Answer (score 3):

What Jongware said about [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com) is correct, but I'd just like to recommend that you read the [Help Center](//apple.stackexchange.com/help) first, because the question you're asking *might* be closed there: it's for power users of Apple hardware and software, and the thing you're asking about isn't *necessarily* about either. The moderation there is quite strict (almost on par with Stack Overflow and possibly a bit stricter), so be careful about what you choose to ask.

I have a feeling it would do better on [Super User](//superuser.com), but that might just be me.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'More Stack Exchange Communities' section of the Stack Exchange drop down, there is a text area that can be typed in.

Typing in 'Apple' (as there are more things to Apple than just Macintoshes...) provides:

[image: Stack Exchange Multicollider SuperDropdown]

Note that this is *just* answering the 'should there be a mac subdomain' - yes, there is, it already exists and that is how you find it.  I am *not* attempting to answer if the question would be on topic on any given site.

Do remember that things are different (and not just the title there). Do not expect any Stack Exchange community to be like any other except for the highest levels of question and answer.  Trying to apply Stack Overflow sensibilities to another site may get you rather confused.